# How can I fix bad screen tearing on Ubuntu 15.10 with an Nvidia GTX 960?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, video

When I play games or watch videos, there is very noticeable screen tearing.

- I have tried turning on vsync in both the game and the nvidia
  settings (sync to vblank).
- I have tried setting the image quality and powermizer to best
  performance.
- I have tried setting 'force full screen redraw' in
  compizconfig-settings-manager.
- I tried adding the intel section to xorg.conf with 'tearfree' option
  set to true.
- I tried setting the -bs option in lighdm 50-server-command.conf
- I also tried to use the 355.11 drivers.

None of that has helped.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, GTX 960, and am using the proprietary 352.55 nvidia drivers. I have an intel i5 processor.

What else can I try?

Comment: can you go into your bios and increase the amount of video memory?

Comment: I can increase Intel video memory allocation up to 512mb that's my only option. Currently It's at 64mb.

Comment: Did you do it? / was it helpful?

Comment: @j0h I just tried increasing to 512 and it had no effect on the screen tearing.

Answer (score -1):

Had same problem in xfce 15.10. Switching the windows compositor solved my issue

http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu!  Links are great, but if they get moved or deleted your answer becomes useless.  Please quote the website instead of just posting a link.